# MySQL datetime to echo on PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show in my page that the database they were looking at was last modified on a certain date & time. I have the following code for that:

```
 $lastUpdate = $pdo->prepare("SELECT lastUpdate FROM bng WHERE lastUpdate IN 
                            (SELECT max(lastUpdate) FROM bng)");
$lastUpdate->execute();
```

As I mentioned in the title, I want to echo the result on my page, I tried:

```
<?php
echo '<p>Database Last Modified  on '.date("l, d F Y - h:i:s A",strtotime($lastUpdate)).'</p>';
?>
```

but it gives me the wrong data and an error message

> Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string,

Hope this question makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `WHERE IN`? Jjust use `SELECT MAX(lastUpdate) FROM bng`

Comment: the result shown on my page is "Database Last Modified on Thursday, 01 January 1970 - 12:00:00 AM" while my sql query is saying "2017-04-12 13:58:28
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$lastUpdate` is a PDO statement, not the value from the database. You need to call `fetch()` and then extract the value from the row.

```
$lastUpdate = $pdo->prepare("SELECT max(lastUpdate) AS lastUpdate FROM bng");
$lastUpdate->execute();
$row = $lastUpdate->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '<p>Database Last Modified  on '.date("l, d F Y - h:i:s A",strtotime($row['lastUpdate'])).'</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine check your variable `$lastUpdate` and change that date into string

```
echo '<p>Database Last Modified  on '.date("l, d F Y - h:i:s A",strtotime("1-1-2017")).'</p>';
```

[Fetch Query from database check this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)